# How do you override a linter-jscs preset?

Tags: atom-editor, jscs

I'd like to override the `disallowMultipleVarDecl` property in [linter-jscs](https://atom.io/packages/linter-jscs). I tried doing the following in `.jscsrc`:

```
{
    "preset": "airbnb",
    "esnext": true,

    "requireTrailingComma": null,
    "disallowMultipleVarDecl": false
}
```

I've quit (not x-ed out) Atom and re-opened it multiple times, and I'm still getting an error:

[image]

How can I override this `disallowMultipleVarDecl` property?

Comment: i'm having similar issue. jscs overrides seem to be ignored.

Comment: You're doing it right, according to the documentation you override a preset default with null or false. I tried this locally (latest Atom and jscs so maybe you can upgrade if you're not on latest) and it works fine. As soon as I use your snippet, the warning goes away.

Comment: Where do I put the .jscsrc file? In the root of the project?